# Script works in CMD but not in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this script below to track process time of each part of my script. When I run this in a CMD prompt, it works perfectly, but when put into a .bat, it fails to run. This is also constructed in two IF statements.
Also shout out to @driblio who I got this from.

```
@echo off

set starttime=%TIME%
set startcsec=%STARTTIME:~9,2%
set startsecs=%STARTTIME:~6,2%
set startmins=%STARTTIME:~3,2%
set starthour=%STARTTIME:~0,2%
set /a starttime=(%starthour%*60*60*100)+(%startmins%*60*100)+(%startsecs%*100)+(%startcsec%)

::Process

set endtime=%time%
set endcsec=%endTIME:~9,2%
set endsecs=%endTIME:~6,2%
set endmins=%endTIME:~3,2%
set endhour=%endTIME:~0,2%
if %endhour% LSS %starthour% set /a endhour+=24
set /a endtime=(%endhour%*60*60*100)+(%endmins%*60*100)+(%endsecs%*100)+(%endcsec%)

set /a timetaken= ( %endtime% - %starttime% )
set /a timetakens= %timetaken% / 100
set timetaken=%timetakens%.%timetaken:~-2%

echo.
echo Took: %timetaken% sec.
```

Comment: Since you do not show this code within your bat file... I am going to guess that you have this code buried within a FOR LOOP or an IF construct. If so, this won't work because your variables are expanded at LOAD time and not at RUN time. You could use delayed expansion... but in this case it would be easier to make subroutines out of these and CALL them from your bat file. Of course you will have to pass starttime value into the 2nd subroutine. Posting incomplete code almost always generates downvotes... as you can see that already happened.

Comment: So you're saying to set an starttime and endtime within the construct

Comment: No... that won't work unless you use delayed expansion... which I am not suggesting.. especially if you are new to it.. Make 2 subroutines... 1 for start and 1 for end using your code above.. Post all of the code if you can.

Answer (score 4):

Read *entire* `set /?`

> Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by `0x` for
>   hexadecimal numbers, and `0` for octal numbers. So `0x12` is the same
>   as `18` is the same as `022`. Please note that the **octal notation can
>   be confusing**: `08` and `09` are **not valid numbers** because `8` and
>   `9` are not valid octal digits.

So `echo "%startttime%"` *could* return something like

```
" 9:08:09.04"
    ↑↑          invalid in set /a 08
       ↑↑       invalid in set /a 09
          ↑↑      valid in set /a 04
```

Use

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set starttime=%TIME%
rem debugging output echo "%starttime%"
set /A startcsec=1%STARTTIME:~9,2% %% 100
set /A startsecs=1%STARTTIME:~6,2% %% 100
set /A startmins=1%STARTTIME:~3,2% %% 100
set starthour=%STARTTIME:~0,2%
set /a starttime=(%starthour%*60*60*100)+(%startmins%*60*100)+(%startsecs%*100)+(%startcsec%)
rem debugging output set start

::Process
:: pause to ensure that endtime >> starttime
pause

set endtime=%time%
rem debugging output echo "%endtime%"
set /A endcsec=1%endTIME:~9,2% %% 100
set /A endsecs=1%endTIME:~6,2% %% 100
set /A endmins=1%endTIME:~3,2% %% 100
set endhour=%endTIME:~0,2%
if %endhour% LSS %starthour% set /a endhour+=24
set /a endtime=(%endhour%*60*60*100)+(%endmins%*60*100)+(%endsecs%*100)+(%endcsec%)
rem debugging output set end

set /a timetaken= ( %endtime% - %starttime% )
set /a timetakens= %timetaken% / 100
set timetaken=%timetakens%.%timetaken:~-2%

echo.
echo Took: %timetaken% sec.
```

Please note that above code snippet still depends on locale and user preferences. For *locale and user preference* **independent** solution, use output from  `wmic os get localdatetime` rather than `%time%` as follows:

```
for /F %%G in ('wmic OS get localdatetime /Value ^| find "="') do @set %%G
```

Then, `%localdatetime%` would contain something like `20170413030820.447000+120` in (fixed-length) [CIM_DATETIME format `yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx) where the fields in the format are

> - `yyyy`  Four-digit year (0000 through 9999). Your implementation can restrict the supported range. For example, an implementation can
>     support only the years 1980 through 2099.
> - `mm`    Two-digit month (01 through 12).
> - `dd`    Two-digit day of the month (01 through 31). This value must be appropriate for the month. For example, February 31 is not valid.
>     However, your implementation does not have to check for valid data.
> - `HH`    Two-digit hour of the day using the 24-hour clock (00 through 23).
> - `MM`    Two-digit minute in the hour (00 through 59).
> - `SS`    Two-digit number of seconds in the minute (00 through 59).
> - `mmmmmm`    Six-digit number of microseconds in the second (000000 through 999999). Your implementation does not have to support
>     evaluation using this field. However, this field must always be
>     present to preserve the fixed-length nature of the string.
> - `s` Plus sign (+) or minus sign (-) to indicate a positive or negative offset from Coordinated Universal Times (UTC).
> - `UUU`   Three-digit offset indicating the number of minutes that the originating time zone deviates from UTC. For WMI, it is encouraged,
>     but not required, to convert times to GMT (a UTC offset of zero).

Comment: consider: `wmic` is slooow. So if you want to be precise to centiseconds, `wmic` is out.